# Meta Reviews on TeX.SX main review page

Tags: discussion, new-features

Is this a new feature or just a temporary bug?  Meta TeX.SX Reviews link in TeX.SX review page *suddenly* appeared when reloading the `Reviews` page of TeX.SX.

The Meta.SX site does not say anything about this (at least I found nothing about it)

[image]

**Edit**

In the meantime there is a general question on this on Meta.SX 
[Meta reviews on review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248511).

Comment: Just came here to ask the same thing! :-)

Comment: See [Meta reviews on review page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248511)

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Thanks, but that question has been posted *after* mine. At the time of my post there was no such question.

Comment: I find this addition to the reviews page quite silly.

Comment: @Werner: I some sense it is, as the Meta Reviews is most times 'dead' ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no answer to the Meta.SX question ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently even the link provided by Martin Schröder ([Meta reviews on review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248511)) can't really answer my question, perhaps there is no answer at all.

We have to take it as it is...

It would be better to highlight the active Meta Review as the `orange` rectangle like for the main site as well.

I decided to answer this question in order to 'close' it.

Comment: This is actually listed as part of the [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/168244): 2015-02-13 [Review page on main sites now links to reviews on meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248511/168244).